# newrelic with angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, newrelic

So i have been trying all 1. pages on google to find an answer to this however without any luck.

**The Issue**

I am trying to use NewRelics browser monitor. For this reason i have added the code snippet from their website and added it to the top of my application:

[image]

Now this seems to be working as i am able to view data:

[image]

However sadly neither the pages nor the javascript errors are being reported.

And when i attempt to go into my session i get alot of funny data:

[image]

So i set out to find a solution:

**What ive tried**

1. i attempted to bower install a module that was suppose to work:

[angular-ra-newrelic](https://libraries.io/bower/angular-ra-newrelic)

However this made no changes.

I then attempted to make my own decorator using the following example:

[Sending AngularJS Errors To New Relic](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2859-sending-angularjs-errors-to-new-relic-raygun-sentry-etc.htm)

Sadly without any results.

So here i am kinda stranded with their support not responding for atleast a few days. Therefor i was hoping some of you guys might be able to help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need make your custom exception handler and send there data to new relic. This code works for me

```js
function ErrProvider() {
    this.$get = ['$log', '$window',
        function($log, $window) {
            return function(exception, cause) {
                // send to new relic
                if ($window.NREUM) {
                    $window.NREUM.noticeError(exception)
                }

                // standard behaviour
                $log.error.apply($log, arguments);
            };

    }]; 
}

export default angular
    .module('app-errors', [
    ])
    .provider('$exceptionHandler', ErrProvider);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried them yet, but here are a couple more angular/new relic helpers that may be easier than rolling your own:

https://github.com/prestonvanloon/newrelic-angular

https://github.com/uken/newrelic-timing